# In codebuild with github push event, git show -s errors with message fatal: unable to parse commit <sha>

Tags: github, continuous-integration, xcodebuild, aws-codebuild

I am trying to read the commit message in my codebuild script when I receive a push event from github.  My main goal is to skip the build with a message that has `skip ci` in it like travis or other ci tools.

`git show -s --format=%s` (or `git show` with any options) results in:

```
error: Could not read <previous SHA here> 
fatal: unable to parse commit <previous SHA here>
```

`git log -1 --pretty=%s` also results in an error.

I used `git rev-parse --is-shallow-repository` to see that it is a shallow repository and I have tried to use `git fetch --unshallow` but that resulted in this message:
`error in object: unshallow <SHA from a couple months ago>`.

Some git commands that I know do work

- git commit and git push (after setting up credentials)
- git checkout $branch_name
- git pull (after setting up credentials)
- git status

Does anyone know how to read a commit message from a push event in codebuild?

I would also like to make a note that the `Source Version` in the aws console is the commit SHA. When I manually click start build and provide a branch name `git show --<options>` works

Answer (score 7):

I realized that my issue was because in my aws codebuild project configuration, there is a git clone depth option and it was set to "1". I set it to "full" and it now works

Answer (score 0):

`git cat-file` will print details about just the one commit, and you can pluck the commit message from the output.

```bash
$ git cat-file -p $CODEBUILD_SOURCE_VERSION

tree de60715e166beccca8d3d8b545ad38ba4a90e41b
parent 2645cf2643845f34032cf9b8996f8ad141425462
author [Me] <...> 1654272805 -0400
committer [Me] <...> 1654272805 -0400

This is the subject line of the commit

The remainder of the commit body is printed below. I'm specifying
this to say that it won't necessarily be straightforward to head
and tail this output, for example.
```

This will also work in both cases of a commit hash and a branch name.

I didn't want to change the git clone depth to full for several reasons. The problem with `git show`, `git log`, and others is that they're porcelain commands that refer to commits other than the one you're looking at. `git cat-file` is a plumbing command so it's not doing anything you're not expecting, and should always work as long as you pass a valid ref.